# Change the position of Radio button in radio group in appery.io using css

Tags: html, css, radio-button, radio-group

[image]

This is the image of the ui-radio that I got after implementing the default component provided in the appery.io web-based development platform.

How can I get the radio-button position on the top? As shown in the image below:

[image]

I have tried with:

```
.ui-radio .ui-btn.ui-radio { 
    position: absolute; 
    vertical-align: top; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
```

Still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-radio .ui-btn.ui-radio { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
```

try this.